# Using the Tooling API to query a workflowalert with a fullname more than 80 characters fails with UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION

Tags: rest-api, workflow, tooling-api

**Summary**

Using the Tooling API to query a workflowalert with a fullname more than 80 characters will result in an error similar to the following:

> ERROR:- UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please
>   include this ErrorId if you contact support: 922686058-1997209
>   (-435199921)

The fullname is comprised of three pieces. The object API name followed by a period and then the API name of the workflow alert. For example, "Account.my_workflowalert" or "my_object__c.my_workflowalert".

**Steps to Reproduce**

If the combined length of the three components is more than 80 characters the issue will be demonstrated.

1) Working 
Create an Email Alert on Account with the following name: 
email_alert_72_678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012

Execute the following REST API query 
/services/data/v33.0/tooling/query?q=select+id,fullname+from+workflowalert

This succeeds as "Account.email_alert_72_678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012" is <= 80 characters in length (7 + 1 + 72)

2) Not working 
Create an Email Alert on Account with the following name: 
email_alert_73_6789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123

Execute the following REST API query 
/services/data/v33.0/tooling/query?q=select+id,fullname+from+workflowalert

This fails as "Account.email_alert_73_6789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123" is > 80 characters in length (7 + 1 + 73)

> [ {  "message" : "An unexpected error occurred. Please include this
>   ErrorId if you contact support: 1482607886-48495 (-435199921)", 
>   "errorCode" : "UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"  } ]

Answer (score 2):

> Salesforce support confirmed that this is indeed a bug and their
>   Research & Development team is working on this case and the matter is
>   under our observation. Here is the Known Issue record for this Bug :
>   https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YNBAA2

**Workaround (until salesforce releases a fix)**

The only way for this to function is not query the fullname for for records with a fullname of length > 80. This can be done by either not querying the fullname field or excluding the problematic entries by ID.